# How to get the optimal optimization variables in Pulp with Python?

Tags: python, pulp

I am using Pulp with Python to solve an optimization problem.

I am using

```
import pulp
# code
pulp.prob.objective.value()
```

Now, I would like to access the optimization variables. How to do this?

In the [documentation of Pulp](http://www.optimization-online.org/DB_FILE/2011/09/3178.pdf), I found something like `use_vars[i].varValue` but I should loop to get the whole vector. Can I get it directly like in the objective value? Anyone familiar with Pulp?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To get the whole optimization vector you can do

```
pulp.prob.variables()
```

which will return a list of all your variables. To access the i-th element of your list, or the i-th variables, you have to do

```
pulp.prob.variables()[i].varValue
```

You can return the objective value and the variables in a function like

```
return pulp.prob.objective.value(), pulp.prob.variables()
```

and then access your variables using a for loop like

```
varsdict = {}
for v in prob.variables():
    varsdict[v.name] = v.varValue
```

Final results will be a dictionary `varsdict` that looks like

```
varsdict = {'x_10': 0.0, 'x_0': 1.0, ...}
```